# stored procedure returns many records but datareader sees only one

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I created a SQL Server stored procedure in which I use a cursor and I created an ASP.NET method to execute that procedure. I'm using a `SqlDataReader` and `while(reader.Read())` to read the values. The problem is that the cursor in the stored procedure returns many rows, but the method reads the first record only. Anyone can help?

stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure [dbo].[GetMenusUserGroupCanView] 
(
  @UserGroupID int
 ,@LanguageID int
) as begin

    declare @MenuID int

    declare @Title varchar(255)

    declare db_cursor cursor for
    (
        select MenuID
        from TrioGate.dbo.Sys_UserGroupMenus
        where UserGroupID=@UserGroupID and ViewFlag='true'
    )

    open db_cursor  

    fetch next from db_cursor into @MenuID  

    while @@fetch_status = 0 begin  

        select 
         Sys_Menus.MenuID
        ,Sys_Menus.ParentMenuID
        ,Sys_Menus.DescriptionLabelID
        ,Sys_Menus.TitleLabelID
        ,Sys_Menus.TooltipLabelID
        ,Sys_Menus.[Icon]
        ,Sys_Menus.[MenuName]
        ,Sys_Menus.[MenuTypeID] as MenuType
        ,[dbo].[Get_ParentMenu_Name](Sys_Menus.ParentMenuID) as ParentMenuName
        ,[dbo].[Get_Label_Description](Sys_Menus.TitleLabelID,1) as Title
        ,[dbo].[Get_Label_Description](Sys_Menus.TooltipLabelID,1) as Tooltip
        ,[dbo].[Get_Label_Description](Sys_Menus.DescriptionLabelID,1) as [Description]
        ,Sys_Menus.[MainTableName] as [Table]
        ,Sys_Menus.[Seq],Sys_Menus.[MenuPath],Sys_Menus.ActivateLog,Sys_Menus.MenuID 
        from Sys_Menus 
            left join Sys_LabelDetails
            on Sys_Menus[TitleLabelID] = Sys_LabelDetails[LabelID]
        where Sys_LabelDetails.LanguageID = @LanguageID 
        and MenuID = @MenuID     

        fetch next from db_cursor into @MenuID  

    end

    close db_cursor  
    deallocate db_cursor 

end
```

Method:

```
public List<Menu> GetMenusUserGroupCanView(int UserGroupID, int LanguageID)
{
    List<Menu> list = new List<Menu>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetMenusUserGroupCanView ", Connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGroupID", UserGroupID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageID", LanguageID);
    try
    {

        Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Menu entry = new Menu();
            entry.MenuID = (int)reader["MenuID"];
            entry.ParentMenuID = (int)reader["ParentMenuID"];
            entry.ActivateLog = (bool)reader["ActivateLog"];
            entry.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
            entry.DescriptionLabelID = (int)reader["DescriptionLabelID"];
            entry.Icon = (byte[])reader["Icon"];
            entry.MainTableName = reader["Table"].ToString();

            entry.MenuName = reader["MenuName"].ToString();
            entry.MenuPath = reader["MenuPath"].ToString();
            entry.MenuTypeID = reader["MenuType"].ToString();
            entry.ParentMenuName = reader["ParentMenuName"].ToString();
            entry.Seq = (int)reader["Seq"];

            entry.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
            entry.TitleLabelID = (int)reader["TitleLabelID"];
            entry.Tooltip = reader["Tooltip"].ToString();
            entry.ToolTipLabelID = (int)reader["ToolTipLabelID"];
            list.Add(entry);
        }

    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your SQL.

Comment: And also show us your C# method calling that stored procedure and reading the data!

Comment: hmm sounds like you're using to using programming against an Oracle database.

Comment: No sql server database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each iteration of your loop performs a select. So, instead of one set of multiple *records*, you're getting multiple *sets*.

Choose your destiny:

**A.** (treat the symptom): advance your reader between resultsets with `IDataReader.NextResult()`

or **B.** (fix the problem): There's no need for that cursor; **use a join instead**:

```sql
select
 * /* dump your columns back in here */
from Sys_UserGroupMenus as g
    join Sys_Menus as m
        join Sys_LabelDetails as d
        on d.LabelID = m.TitleLabelID
        and d.LanguageID = @LanguageID
    on m.MenuID = g.MenuID
where g.UserGroupID = @UserGroupID
and g.ViewFlag = 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks for All,Thank you canon I really used the join and it worked,and also I tried to use the first solution with bool flag=true; while (reader.Read()||flag){.... flag=reader.NextResult();} and It worked too